# How to avoid css transformation(rotate) when removing class?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to rotate element onclick by adding CSS class to it. Problem is, when that same CSS class is removed, element is rotated for the second time.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L3x2zhd1/1/

JS:

```
var el = document.getElementById('el');

el.onclick = function() {
    el.className = 'rotate'
    setTimeout(function(){
    el.className = ''
    },1000)
};
```

CSS:

```
#el {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
    transition: transform 1s;

}

.rotate {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
```

How can I avoid this?

Comment: place the `transition: transform 1s` (and vendor prefixes) on the .rotate class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to place the `transition: transform 1s` (and related vendor prefixes) on the `.rotate` css rule:

Reason for double animation:
You had defined the transition property on the root element. As a result when it was trying to come to its normal position, it was again rotating due to `transition`.

```js
var el = document.getElementById("el");

el.addEventListener("click", function() {
  el.classList.add("rotate");
  setTimeout(function() {
    el.classList.remove("rotate");
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
#el {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.rotate {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="el">test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just toggle the class instead of adding and removing it.

```js
$('#el').click(function(){
$(this).toggleClass('rotate');
});
```

```css
#el {
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 background-color: red;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s;

}

.rotate {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="el"></div>
```

Comment: OP mentions nothing about wanting to use jQuery

Comment: I want to use vanilla JS for this :)

Comment: Then apply that login to vanilla JavaScript?